# efficient renaming of strings based on comma delimited table

Tags: bash, rename

I want to rename multiple individual entries in a long file based on a comma delimited table. I figured out a way how to do it, but I feel it's highly inefficient and I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it.

My file contains >30k entries like this this:

```
>Gene.1::Fmerg_contig0.1::g.1::m.1 Gene.1::Fmerg_contig0.1::g.1
TPAPHKMQEPTTPFTPGGTPKPVFTKTLKGDVVEPGDGVTFVCEVAHPAAYFITWLKDSK
>Gene.17::Fmerg_Transcript_1::g.17::m.17 Gene.17::Fmerg_Transcript_1::g.17  
PLDDKLADRVQQTDAGAKHALKMTDEGCKHTLQVLNCRVEDSGIYTAKATDENGVWSTCS
>Gene.15::Fmerg_Transcript_1::g.15::m.15 Gene.15::Fmerg_Transcript_1::g.15
AQLLVQELTEEERARRIAEKSPFFMVRMKPTQVIENTNLSYTIHVKGDPMPNVTFFKDDK
```

And the table with the renaming information looks like this:

```
original,renamed
Fmerg_contig0.1,Fmerg_Transcript_0
Fmerg_contig1.1,Fmerg_Transcript_1
Fmerg_contig2.1,Fmerg_Transcript_2
```

The inefficient solution I came up with looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#script to revert dammit name changes

while read line; do
    IFS="," read -r -a contig <<< "$line"
    sed -i "s|${contig[1]}|${contig[0]}|g" Fmerg_final.fasta.transdecoder_test.pep
done < Fmerg_final.fasta.dammit.namemap.csv
```

However, this means that sed iterates over the table once per entry to be renamed.

I could imagine there is a way to only access each line once and iterate over the name list that way, but I'm not sure how to tackle this. I chose bash because this is the language that I'm most fluent in. But I'm not adverse to use perl or python if they offer an easier solution.

Comment: create a pre-step that builds a group of sed commands, all in 1 file, each `s/str/rep/` on a line by itself, the inside your `loop`, `sed -i'' -f mySedScript.sed "$file"`(run it on test data first!). (*Why can't genetic tools output single line records? That adds to the complexity of all of these problems.*) Good luck!

Comment: Have you viewed my answer ?

Comment: Hi Mike,
Sorry, I got busy with some other work I had to do. I'll have to digest your answer for a while to make sure I understand how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is On problem and you solved it with On solution so I wouldn't consider it inefficient. However, if you are good with bash you can do more it no problem.

**Divide and conquer.** 
I have done this many times as you can reduce the work time closer to the time it takes one item to be processed ..

Take this pseudo code, I call a method that cuts up the 30K file into say X parts, then I call it in a loop with the & option to run as threads.

```
declare -a file_part_names

# cut files into parts
function cut_file_into_parts() {
    orig_file="$1"
    number_parts="$1"

}

# call method to handle renaming a file
function rename_fields_in_file() {
    file_part="$1"
    while read line; do
    IFS="," read -r -a contig <<< "$line"
    sed -i "s|${contig[1]}|${contig[0]}|g" "$tmp_file"
done < "$file_part"
}

# main
cut_file_into_parts "Fmerg_final.fasta.dammit.namemap.csv"

for each file_part ;do
   if threads_pids < 100

      rename_fields_in_file $each &
   else
      sleep 10
   fi
done
wait
#Now that you have a pile of temp files processed, combine them all.

for each temp file do
  temp_$i.txt >> final_result.txt
done
```

In summary, cut the big file into say 500 tmp files labled file1, file2 etc. in say /tmp/folder. Then go through them one at a time but launch them as child processes up to say 100 running at the same time, keep the pipe full by checking that if over 100 do nothing (sleep 10) if under add more. When done, one more loop to combine file1_finish.txt to file2_finish.txt etc. which is super quick.

NOTE: if this is too much you can always just break the file up and call the the same script X times for each file instead of using threads.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I understand what you were suggesting. Even though my coding skills were not quite good enough to turn it into a working program, it helped in my understanding of the topic.

Comment: Sorry if I was too over the top. Take your original script, then create a script that takes your big file and chops it up into say 100 files. Then run your script on each of the 100 files. writing to their own output files, then combine the files. Once you have that working, you can run the original script with & and call it X number of times at once. when they are all finished you combine them.  This is hard concept to explain I am realizing lol good luck. If you give me samples I will show you a finished example.